# Passing Date value to NetSuite via API

Tags: netsuite

When populating a date field in NetSuite via the API (e.g Sales Order start date), you are required to specify a timestamp + timezone, even though the timestamp isn't shown in NetSuite.

Does anyone know the logic NetSuite is using to covert a date+timestamp to a date?

For example, sometimes when I pass a date+time of Oct 1 2016 00:00:00 UTC, I see Sept 30 2016 in NetSuite. Other times, I see the date appear as Oct 1 2016 in NetSuite. The logic seems inconsistent. Can anyone explain the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it depended on my timezone, and the timezone of the account that was writing to NetSuite.

I had this issue in the past.  I resolved it by setting my Integration user account to have GMT timezone.  After that, the dates/times have always appeared correct for each user, based on their timezone (set in preferences).

Comment: After some trial and error, I tried switch the API user and setting their timezone to GMT. That appears to have worked - hopefully it doesn't revert back. All I can think of is that our integration tool maintained an open session with the original API user, and their timezone change didn't take effect immediately.

Answer (score 0):

the date you submitted is converted from logged-in user's timezone, to server's timezone. it's saved with the server timezone.

so depending on the difference between timezones of session user and server, yes it can even change the date by conversion.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, here the conclusion I've come to: The date+time submitted via API is converted to the logged in user's timezone. NetSuite then strips off the time and defaults the time to the start of the day (in the company's timezone). Internally, NetSuite then stores the date as a date+time the server's local timezone (typically pacific time).